# how to convert std::string to QString

Tags: c++, qt, string

I have a problem:

```
std::string str("character/test/raw");
qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(str);
```

and the output is:

```
"]AIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII"
```

I think the problem is in encoding but don't know how to fix it. Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your QT compiled with STL compatible enabled option?

Maybe you can use [fromUtf8](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#fromUtf8) or one of other static functions of QString.

Comment: I've installed the vc++2008 compiled last version from qt.nokia.com

Comment: qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(str.data(), str.size()); That helped, thanks

Comment: @Andrew `QString::fromUtf8( str.c_str() )` should be enough.

Answer (score 9):

string to const char*, then to qstring

```
std::string str("character/test/raw");
QString qstr(str.c_str());
qDebug() << qstr;
```